# NodeJS - morgan immediate option default value

Tags: node.js, logging, morgan

As per [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan), `morgan` takes two arguments - format string and options object. The options object mentions:

> **immediate**
>
> Write log line on request instead of response. This means that a
>   requests will be logged even if the server crashes, but data from the
>   response (like the response code, content length, etc.) cannot be
>   logged.

I am not clear, what is the default value for `immediate` as I am not using the `options` object at all. Is it a boolean?

On my Mac, I can see logs of my NodeJS application. When ported to Windows as a binary, all response items (status, content-length and response time) are not reported (i.e. seen as dashes).

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look into the [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js) reveals the default options object is `{}`.

```
 59  function morgan (format, options) {
 60    var fmt = format
 61    var opts = options || {}                // opts == {}
```

So to answer the question it is not a boolean, but because of the way things are handled along the way

```
133  if (immediate) {                         // immediate == undefined
134    // immediate log
135    logRequest()
136  } else {
137    // record response start
138    onHeaders(res, recordStartTime)
139
140    // log when response finished
141    onFinished(res, logRequest)
142  }
```

the *default* value is *falsey* and therefore the logging is done after the response is finished.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and reference to source code! How is 'after the response is finished' identified?